# Powershell command to update IP address in Azure CosmosDB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to update firewall rules by adding a single IP in Azure Cosmos DB.

I am using command

```
# Get existing IP Rules
$databaseAccountIpRules = (Get-AzCosmosDBAccount -ResourceGroupName $dbResourceGroup -Name $dbAccount).IpRules

# Append IP Rules
$databaseAccountIpRules += $customIP

# Upload the updated IP Rules
Update-AzCosmosDBAccount -ResourceGroupName $databaseResourceGroup -Name $databaseAccount -IpRule $databaseAccountIpRules
```

This is giving me an error -

```
Update-AzCosmosDBAccount: Could not parse supplied IpAddressOrRange: 'Microsoft.Azure.Management.CosmosDB.Models.IpAddressOrRange'. Please ensure correct IPv4 formatting and CIDR notation for IP range.
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I needed to do this

```
# Get existing IP Rules
$databaseAccountIpRules = (Get-AzCosmosDBAccount -ResourceGroupName $dbResourceGroup -Name $dbAccount).IpRules.IpAddressOrRangeProperty

# Append IP Rules
$databaseAccountIpRules += $customIP

# Upload the updated IP Rules
Update-AzCosmosDBAccount -ResourceGroupName $databaseResourceGroup -Name $databaseAccount -IpRule $databaseAccountIpRules
```